# Array fills with null + element

Tags: java, arrays, null

I can't figure out why my rows array fills with null + the element I am trying to put in it?

Output: nullelement, nullelement, nullelement

```java
int numColumns = kbd.nextInt();

String columns = "";

kbd.nextLine();
for(int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
    if (i == numColumns - 1) {
        System.out.printf("Enter Column %d: ", i + 1);
        columns += kbd.nextLine() + " VARCHAR(100)";
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Enter Column %d: ", i + 1);
        columns += kbd.nextLine() + " VARCHAR(100),";
    }
}
create(tableName, columns);
System.out.printf("\nHow many rows would you like your table to have? ");
int numRows = kbd.nextInt();
kbd.nextLine();
System.out.printf("\nFill in the %d columns: \n", numColumns);
String [] rows = new String[numColumns];

for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++){
            System.out.printf("Enter Row %d: ", i + 1);
            rows[j] += kbd.nextLine();
    }
    write(tableName,rows);
    Arrays.fill(rows, null);
}
```

Thank you for any insight and help!

Comment: `String [] rows = new String[numColumns];` creates an array of `null` values. So later, `rows[j] += kbd.nextLine();` is trying concatenate with a `null`.

Comment: Thank you so much, figured it out like 5 min after posting <3